# Change interior color of the previously selected cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to do something simple in Excel:

1. Select a random cell I want its interior colour changed of.
2. Click a specific cell with the color change code attached to it.

Simply put; I want to click any cell I want, then click cell F1 and have the previously selected cell turn blue.

What I have is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$F$1")) Is Nothing Then
ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbBlue
End If
End Sub
```

The problem here of course is that "ActiveCell" has changed by the time its run in the code. I'd need something like "PreviouslyActiveCell" but I don't think it exists and don't know how to get there another way.

Help always appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT**: the linked question helped me solve it. Thanks everyone! My working code is now:

> ```
> Public PreviousActiveCell As Range
>
> Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
> Static pPrevious As Range
> Set PreviousActiveCell = pPrevious
> Set pPrevious = ActiveCell
>
> If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$F$1")) Is Nothing Then
> PreviousActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbBlue 
> End If 
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What about select F1, then click [Format Painter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-format-painter-4bb415a9-d4e4-42b7-b579-170adc594e40) and click your random cell?